# Extract n lines of every m lines in a list

Tags: python, list, split

I have a data column of 828 values. In the column, it repeats numbers 1-18 many times instead. I want a new column that will grab 5 lines of every 18 so it can repeat 1-5 many times. This is not exactly what my data looks like but the method is the same of what I want to do to my actual data.

My data column with the repeating 1-18 is stored in df_rois

I tried this line of code but it just skips every 5 without keeping the numbers in between:

```
df_rois2 = df_rois[::5]
```

What I currently have in df_rois:

```
[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18]
```

What I want in df_rois2:

```
[ 1 2 3 4 5 1 2 3 4 5 1 2 3 4 5 1 2 3 4 5 1 2 3 4 5]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop through the 18-length slices and extract the first 5 elements, then use `extend` to add them to `df_rois2`:

```
df_rois2 = []

for i in range(0, len(df_rois), 18):
    df_rois2.extend(df_rois[i:i + 5])

print(df_rois2)
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: I just copied and pasted your provided code and my output is just all 0's. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Nycbros It depends on how you used it, what's the example you used?

Comment: Sorry. In my code there was more than one column and I just didn't index properly. Thanks for the help!